# C# Project Rebuilding Due to Resx File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am using VS 2013 and MSBuild.  I have a project that is always rebuilding due to a resx file.  I can tell by this due to the following line in my log:

```
Input file "obj\Release\Assembly.Properties.Resources.resources" is newer than output file "obj\Release\Assembly.pdb".
```

This is created earlier on in the build during the GenerateResource target.

```
Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Release\Assembly.Properties.Resources.resources".
```

How do I stop the resx file from always being processed into the resources file?  This is a very central library in our source code and this recompiling is making our builds much longer.

Here is the project xml for the relevant parts.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>

<Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: You'll need to find out why the .resx file is changing.  Make it read-only and something is going to go bang! when it tries to modify the file.

Comment: .resx file is not changing.  Modified date is several days old.  The processing into the Assembly.Properties.Resources.resources file is causing the rebuild.

Comment: Set the file obj\Release\Assembly.Properties.Resources.resources as readonly and the target GenerateResources failed.  Still unsure as to why this target is always running.

Comment: GenerateResource target.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try "touching" the pdb file's timestamp? This should get rid of the need for rebuild. In the Post-build event you can use the following command:

```
copy /b "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(TargetName).pdb" +,,
```